# Is a linear transformation continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, continuity, linear-transformations

Let f :$ ℝ^n→ℝ^n$ be a linear transformation. Is f always continuous? Can anyone help how to show this?

Comment: Yes. Any linear transformation between finite dimensional vector spaces is continuous.

Comment: Combining two proofs from two Wikipedia pages yields the result: [Proof that linear maps between finite dimensional spaces are bounded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discontinuous_linear_map#A_linear_map_from_a_finite-dimensional_space_is_always_continuous).  [Equivalence of boundedness and continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_operator#Equivalence_of_boundedness_and_continuity).

Comment: The usual (product) topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is assumed (I think).  The continuity of linear transformations is a special case of the continuity of polynomial functions.